# Remove duplicates from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, datetime

I've got a database with over 7000 records. As it turns out, there are several duplicates within those records. I found several suggestions on how to delete duplicates and keep only 1 record. 
But in my case things are a bit more complicated: cases are not simply duplicates if they hold the same data as another record. Instead, several cases ar perfectly okay holding the same data. They are marked as duplicate only when they hold the same data AND are both inserted within 30 seconds.

Therefore I need a SQL statement that deletes duplicates (eg: all fields, except `id` and `datetime`) if they have been inserted within a 40 seconds range (eg: evaluating the `datetime` field).

Since I'm everything but a SQL expert and can't find a suitable solution online, I truly hope some of you might help me out and point me in the right direction. That would be very appreciated!

The table structure is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_ttr_results` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `schoolyear` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `area` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `types` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `tasksWrong` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tasksRight` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tasksData` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `parent_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=68696 ;
```

So just to clarify again, a duplicate case is a case that:

[1]holds the same data as another case for all fields, except the `id` and `datetime` field

[2]is inserted in the DB, according to the `datetime` field, within 40 seconds of another record with the same values

If both conditions are met, all cases except one, should be deleted.

Comment: The id's are always different right? So a duplicate means all columns but the id one?

Comment: @Juru The ID's are always different indeed (hence the auto_increment). Duplicates hold the same data, except for the id and datetime field BUT are inserted within 40 sec of other records holding the same data (again, except the id and datetime fields)

Comment: There is a very peculiar difficulty with your question. Which is the 40 second filtering. If you consider duplicates d1(1), d2(30), d3(41) (with the numbers being the seconds of creation). d2 would be a duplicate to d1, but d3 wouldn't. But d3 would be a duplicate for d2. So is d3 a duplicate or not? To me only d2 would have to be removed this makes the problem very hard to solve.

Answer (score 3):

As @Juru pointed out in the comments, we need quite a surgical knive to cut this one. It is however possible to do this in an iterative way via a stored procedure.

First we use a self-join to identify the first duplicate for every record, that itself is not a duplicate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  MIN(postdups.id AS id)
FROM wp_ttr_results AS base
INNER JOIN wp_ttr_results AS postdups
  ON base.id<postdups.id
  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(postdups.datetime)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(base.datetime)<40
  AND base.user_id=postdups.user_id
  AND base.schoolyear=postdups.schoolyear
  AND base.area=postdups.area
  AND base.content=postdups.content
  AND base.types=postdups.types
  AND base.tasksWrong=postdups.tasksWrong
  AND base.tasksRight=postdups.tasksRight
  AND base.parent_id=postdups.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_ttr_results AS predups
  ON base.id>predups.id
  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(base.datetime)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(predups.datetime)<40
  AND base.user_id=predups.user_id
  AND base.schoolyear=predups.schoolyear
  AND base.area=predups.area
  AND base.content=predups.content
  AND base.types=predups.types
  AND base.tasksWrong=predups.tasksWrong
  AND base.tasksRight=predups.tasksRight
  AND base.parent_id=predups.user_id
WHERE predups.id IS NULL
GROUP BY base.id
;
```

This selects the lowest `id` of all **later** records (`base.id<postdups.id`), that have the same payload as an existing record and are within a 40s window (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dups.datetime)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(base.datetime)<40), but skips those base records, that are duplicates themselves. In @Juru's example, the `:30` record would be hit, as it is a duplicate of the `:00` record, which itself is not a duplicate, but the `:41` record would not be hit, as it is a duplicate only to `:30`, which itself is a duplicate of `:00`.

We have

Now we have to remove this record - since MySQL can't delete from a table it is reading, we must use a variable to achieve that:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cleanUpDuplicatesTemp SELECT DISTINCT 
  -- as above
;
DELETE FROM wp_ttr_results 
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT id FROM cleanUpDuplicatesTemp)
;
DROP TABLE cleanUpDuplicatesTemp
;
```

Until now we will have removed the first duplicate for each record, in the process possibly changing, what would be considered a duplicate ...

Finally we must loop through this process, exiting the loop if the `SELECT DISTINCT` returns nothing.

Putting it all together into a stored proceedure:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE cleanUpDuplicates()
BEGIN
  DECLARE numDuplicates INT;
  iterate: LOOP
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cleanUpDuplicatesTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cleanUpDuplicatesTemp
    SELECT DISTINCT
      MIN(postdups.id AS id)
    FROM wp_ttr_results AS base
    INNER JOIN wp_ttr_results AS postdups
      ON base.id<postdups.id
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(postdups.datetime)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(base.datetime)<40
      AND base.user_id=postdups.user_id
      AND base.schoolyear=postdups.schoolyear
      AND base.area=postdups.area
      AND base.content=postdups.content
      AND base.types=postdups.types
      AND base.tasksWrong=postdups.tasksWrong
      AND base.tasksRight=postdups.tasksRight
      AND base.parent_id=postdups.user_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_ttr_results AS predups
      ON base.id>predups.id
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(base.datetime)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(predups.datetime)<40
      AND base.user_id=predups.user_id
      AND base.schoolyear=predups.schoolyear
      AND base.area=predups.area
      AND base.content=predups.content
      AND base.types=predups.types
      AND base.tasksWrong=predups.tasksWrong
      AND base.tasksRight=predups.tasksRight
      AND base.parent_id=predups.user_id
    WHERE predups.id IS NULL
    GROUP BY base.id;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numDuplicates FROM cleanUpDuplicatesTemp;
    IF numDuplicates<=0 THEN
      LEAVE iterate;
    END IF;
    DELETE FROM wp_ttr_results 
    WHERE id IN
      (SELECT id FROM cleanUpDuplicatesTemp)
  END LOOP iterate;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cleanUpDuplicatesTemp;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Now a simple `CALL cleanUpDuplicates;` should do the trick.

Comment: There is still a problem. Suppose you have duplicate records d1, d2 and d3 when not considering the filtering for the 40 seconds. d1 is created at time 10:00:00 and d2 is created at 10:00:30 and d3 is created at 10:00:41. For d2 d3 is a duplicate, but for d1 it is not. So d2 is a duplicate but d3 not.

Comment: @Juru Not only "good catch", but excellent catch - thank you! I will reconsider.

Comment: I don't think this is doable in SQL. Much easier in a program, each record that is identified as a non duplicate should be taken as a base for filtering out duplicates that come within the next 40 seconds.

Comment: I think the original question want to delete both d2,d3. If not, the question is changed to get a list of events with at least 40 seconds interval or with different attributes. Could be done by a stored procedure.

Comment: @Juru - it is (barely) possible, since we can rely on ordered records and use stored procedures.

Comment: ...and if you create an insert/update trigger which populates an additional column with FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`)/40) and add the column  to a unique index you can prevent addition of more "duplicates"

Comment: @symcbean - ofcourse, but I understood the question to be about sanitizing existing data.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work, but it probably won't be very fast...

```
DELETE FROM dupes 
USING wp_ttr_results AS dupes 
   INNER JOIN wp_ttr_results AS origs 
      ON dupes.field1 = origs.field1 
      AND dupes.field2 = origs.field2 
      AND ....
      AND AS dupes.id <> origs.id 
      AND dupes.`datetime` BETWEEN orig.`datetime` AND (orig.`datetime` + INTERVAL 40 SECOND)
;
```

Comment: I think you will delete everything. You have to check that the dupes.id is different from the origs.id because a row with the same primary key is by definition the same but not a duplicate. The second problem is that you need to keep one row of the duplicates while now you delete every row that is part of a set of duplicates.